# Understanding the difference between 3 observable definitions

Tags: rxjs

All of them is working but I don't know which of them is better.

```
const myObservable1 = Observable.create(function (observer:string) {...}
const myObservable2 = Observable.create(function subscribe(observer:string) {...}
const myObservable3 = Observable.create(function (observer:Observer<string>) {...}
```

Comment: Hello Soheil, this is a great place to start [The RxJS library](https://angular.io/guide/rx-library) or [Learn RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/)